# How To MustOverride Shared/Constructor Function Visual Basic

Tags: database, vb.net, inheritance, constructor, shared

I'm currently using Visual Basic for a College Project which requires us to make a simple database system. For my system I have a base(abstract) class called `Record` which is inherited by the different types of records there are in my database e.g. `Member`, `User`, `Role`.

I am saving my data in csv files and have already written a `CSVHandler` class. However, I want an elegant way of constructing an instance of a class derived from `Record` with a string from the `CSVHandler`.

This is where the problem occurs. The only way I can think of doing this is by making a `Constrcutor` or `Shared Function` in each class derived from `Record`. However, Visual Basic does not allow you make `Constructors` or `Shared Functions` also `MustOverride`.

Here is the code I would expect to write:

```
' Base Class
Public MustInherit Class Record
    Public MustOverride Shared Function fromString(ByVal str as String) As Record
End Class

' Example Of Class Derived From Record
Public Class User
    Inherits Record 

    Private _id As String
    Private _name As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As String, ByVal name As String)
        _id = id
        _name = name
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Shared Function fromString(ByVal str as String) As Record
        Dim strs() As String = str.Split(",")
        Return New User(strs(0), strs(1))
    End Function
End Class

' Example Of Creating Instacnce Of User
Dim user1 = User.fromString("1671,Kappeh")
```

Is there a way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way in .NET to enforce the existence of a `Shared` `Sub` or `Function`.  I've felt the lack before.  In one case, it's a factory method, and since I'm already using reflection to implement the factory, I just require the `Shared` member to be provided by convention (and get it via reflection).  In another case, a routine that logically should be shared ends up being a member function just so that I can require it to be present on a generic argument.

Comment: Why would your college ask you to write a database application without a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is similar to the answer from @jmcilhinney in that it forces the derived class to implement an initialization method. However it makes use of a generic shared function and uses the little known [GetUninitializedObject method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get around using the generic `New` constraint and it's requirement of an accessible parameter-less constructor.

```
Public MustInherit Class Record
    Public Shared Function fromString(Of T As {Record})(ByVal str As String) As T
        ' create an unintialized instance of T 
        Dim ret As T = DirectCast(System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(GetType(T)), T)
        ret.Initialize(str)
        Return ret
    End Function

    Protected MustOverride Sub Initialize(source As String)
End Class
```

The `User` class then would be something like this:

```
Public Class User : Inherits Record
    Private _id As String
    Private _name As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As String, ByVal name As String)
        _id = id
        _name = name
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Initialize(source As String)
        Dim strs() As String = source.Split(","c)
        _id = strs(0)
        _name = strs(1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Example usage:

```
Dim userRecord As User = Record.fromString(Of User)("1,2")
```

Comment: I do like this solution. Although I have a working code, I may give this approach a shot as it is more elegant than mine. It also ties in well with how some of my other code works. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Have your constructor call a `Protected MustOverride` method that does the initialisation.

```
Public MustInherit Class Record

    'This is required because each derived constructor must be able to implicitly invoke a parameterless
    'base constructor if it doesn't explicitly invoke a base constructor with parameters.
    Protected Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(csv As String)
        Init(csv)
    End Sub

    Protected MustOverride Sub Init(csv As String)

End Class

Public Class User
    Inherits Record

    Private Property Id As String
    Private Property Name As String

    'This is still required because you can use a base constructor directly to create a derived instance.
    Public Sub New(csv As String)
        MyBase.New(csv)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(id As String, name As String)
        Id = id
        Name = name
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Init(csv As String)
        'Add your type-specific implementation here.
    End Sub

End Class
```

This "solution" doesn't actually do what I thought it would because, while it forces you to override `Init` in a derived class, you still have to provide a derived constructor that invokes the base constructor that calls `Init` and you still can't enforce that.  I think that I'll leave this as an answer though, because, while it doesn't actually provide a solution to your problem, it demonstrates further why (as far as I can tell) there is no such solution.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I think what I will do is make a `MustOverride Sub` like `setFromString(ByVal str As String)` Which I can use after the instance of the object has been created. It seems to be the only way I can think of to make it enforced.